# CodeIgniter: Avoid Insert Duplicate Records on Page refresh

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I have a form (quote form) and When I fill the form, I have 2 queries running. One query selects the columns from the table and the other query inserts the information in the table. I am Successfully able to fetch and insert the query simultaneously. But the problem is, when I refresh the page, it always inserts duplicate record. How can I avoid this and not insert the records again. I tried few approaches like sessions and if else statement, but it didnt work.

My codes :-

**Model:**

```
 function insertToQuoteForm() {

  $postcode = $this->input->post('pick_add');
  $del_postcode = $this->input->post('drop_add');
  if ($postcode != '' ) {
   $fName = $this->input->post('bk_name');
   $lName = $this->input->post('bk_lname');
   $email = $this->input->post('bk_email');
   $contact = $this->input->post('bk_contact');
   $postcode = $this->input->post('pick_add');
   $del_postcode = $this->input->post('drop_add');
   $carMake = $this->input->post('car_list');
   $carModel = $this->input->post('car_models');
   $carmanYear = $this->input->post('car_man_year');
   $carType = $_POST['bodytypeselect'];
   $insertFormQuery = "INSERT INTO Quote_Form( First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Phone, Origin, Destination, CarMake, CarModel, ManYear, CarType) VALUES
( '" . $fName ."', '" .$lName."', '" . $email."', '" . $contact."', '" . $postcode."', '" . $del_postcode."', '" . $carMake."', '" . $carModel."', '" . $carmanYear."', '" . $carType ."')";
$insertDetails = $this->db->query($insertFormQuery);

   $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
   return $insert_id;

 }
  else {
     redirect ( base_url());

     }
}
```

**Controller:**

I am using a quoteNo to show as a reference number of the last inserted ID

```
$data['quoteNo'] = $this->PostModel->insertToQuoteForm();
```

**The logic is:**

When the viewer fills the quote form to get the estimated amount, it does two thing. Saves the user details in one table and fetches the records from other tables. The data that was inserted in the insert table, will generate the last the ID and that ID will turn as a quote number. Now, if the user refreshes the page, it should still show the same quote number when generated and not get the new generated number. Thanks.

Comment: for that you need to set a cookie when you insert the quote to the database and check for the cookie on each request, if the cookie exists don't insert a new quote.

Comment: @Muhammad how can I set the cookies? Sorry I am new to codeigniter

Comment: you can find a lot of examples on the internet, please read the Codeigniter documentation that will give you enough knowledge about all the things, you may visit the following link for cookies https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Comment: @Muhammad i tried but its not working

Comment: add complete method in the controller. that helps alot to know the problem